# DevExpress XtraGrid set FocusedRowHandle and then scroll focused row into view?

Tags: devexpress, xtragrid, setfocus

I have an XtraGrid with ~500 rows in it. I can set the FocusedRowHandle to, say, row 245. But is there a method that will scroll that now-focused row into view if it's currently not visible?

```
DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView vw;
vw = MyGrid.DefaultView as DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView;
vw.FocusedRowHandle = 245;
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the `GridView.MakeRowVisible` method for this purpose.

Comment: If the data source adds another 10 rows, I scroll to the end with `grid.MakeRowVisible(grid.DataRowCount - 1);` but this "*jumps*" to the end. Is there a way to make it scroll smoothly?